# How to query a list of data to make rows into columns

Tags: linq

I have a list of data like below

```
Item    Vendor  Compliance  Status

I1      V1          C1          Y
I1      V1          C2          N
I1      V1          C3          Y
I1      V2          C1          Y
I1      V2          C2          Y
I2      V1          C3          Y
```

How can I query to make it become

```
Item    Vendor  C1  C2  C3

I1      V1       Y  N   Y    
I1      V2       Y  Y   -
I2      V1       -  -   Y
```

While the compliance might have many, not necessary only have C1, C2, C3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to cheat of @Serv and use a part of the code he used for defining data (*sigh* - yeah I am lazy).

To handle the `dynamic` aspect of having many compliances you can use [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). All you need to do is to get all existing compliance types and for each type assign a property to your object.

```
void Main()
{
    var content = new List<Content>()
    {
        new Content("I1", "V1", "C1", true),
        new Content("I1", "V1", "C2", false),
        new Content("I1", "V1", "C3", true),
        new Content("I1", "V2", "C1", true),
        new Content("I1", "V2", "C2", true),
        new Content("I2", "V1", "C3", true),
        new Content("I2", "V1", "C4", true)
    };

    var compliances = content.Select(c=>c.Compliance).Distinct();
    var temp = content.GroupBy (c => new {Item = c.Item, Vendor = c.Vendor});
    var results = temp.Select (t => 
    {
        dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
        result.Item = t.Key.Item;
        result.Vendor = t.Key.Vendor;
        foreach(var compliance in compliances)
        {
            var isCompliant = t.Any(x => x.Compliance == compliance && x.Status.GetValueOrDefault());
            ((IDictionary<String, Object>)result).Add(compliance, isCompliant);
        }
        return result;
    }).Dump();
}

public class Content
{
    public Content(string item, string vendor, string compliance, bool? status)
    {
        Item = item; Vendor = vendor; Compliance = compliance; Status = status;
    }

    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    public string Compliance { get; set; }
    public bool? Status { get; set; }
}
```

And the results:

[image: Results]

**EDIT**

To get `null` instead of `false` when a compliance does not exist use this code the `foreach` loop:

```
var isCompliant = t.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Compliance == compliance); 
((IDictionary<String, Object>)result).Add(compliance, isCompliant == null ? null : isCompliant.Status);
```

The results will look like this:

[image: Results after edit.]

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: This is www.linqpad.net

Comment: @RePierre. I did not know Expando Object existed until now. Thank you for enlightening me!

Comment: It helped finding a real working solution and you mentioned it. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Your result is wrong. E.g. the first item should be `I1, V1, True, False, True, null`, not `I1, V1, True, False, True, False`.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure I violated a dozen principles of good programming by doing this, but I think this solution works. What I have done is created a class in Linqpad where Status is of type bool (I am lazy).

This is the whole snippet so you can reproduce it:

```
void Main()
{
    var content = new List<Content>()
    {
      new Content("I1", "V1", "C1", true),
      new Content("I1", "V1", "C2", false),
      new Content("I1", "V1", "C3", true),
      new Content("I1", "V2", "C1", true),
      new Content("I1", "V2", "C2", true),
      new Content("I2", "V1", "C3", true)
    };

    var temp = content.GroupBy (c => new {Item = c.Item, Vendor = c.Vendor});
    var result = temp.Select (t => new 
                      {
                          Item = t.Key.Item,
                          Vendor = t.Key.Vendor,
                          C1 = content.Where(x => x.Item == t.Key.Item && x.Vendor == t.Key.Vendor && x.Compliance == "C1").Select (x => x.Status),
                          C2 = content.Where(x => x.Item == t.Key.Item && x.Vendor == t.Key.Vendor && x.Compliance == "C2").Select (x => x.Status),
                          C3 = content.Where(x => x.Item == t.Key.Item && x.Vendor == t.Key.Vendor && x.Compliance == "C3").Select (x => x.Status)
                      }).Dump();

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Content
{
    public Content(string item, string vendor, string compliance, bool? status)
    {
      Item = item; Vendor = vendor; Compliance = compliance; Status = status;
    }

    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    public string Compliance { get; set; }
    public bool? Status { get; set; }

}
```

This is the output, which should give you what you expected:

[image: dummy description]

Comment: Does not work with an arbitrary number of different `Compliance` values.

Comment: Lets try calling Jon Skeets name thrice and hope he appears.

Answer (score 1):

Given your data as:

```
class Data
{
    public int Item {get; set;}
    public int Vendor {get; set;}
    public int Compliance {get; set;}
    public bool Status {get; set;}
}

Data[] data = 
{
    new Data {Item=1, Vendor=1, Compliance=1, Status=true},
    new Data {Item=1, Vendor=1, Compliance=2, Status=false},
    new Data {Item=1, Vendor=1, Compliance=3, Status=true},
    new Data {Item=1, Vendor=2, Compliance=1, Status=true},
    new Data {Item=1, Vendor=2, Compliance=2, Status=true},
    new Data {Item=2, Vendor=1, Compliance=3, Status=true}
};
```

a possible solution could like

```
var compliance = data.Select(d => d.Compliance).Distinct().ToList();

var result = data.GroupBy(d => new {d.Item, d.Vendor})
                 .Select(g => new 
                 {
                     Item = g.Key.Item,
                     Vendor = g.Key.Vendor,
                     Compliance = (from c in compliance
                                   join cs in g.Select(x => new {x.Compliance, x.Status}) on c equals cs.Compliance into j
                                   from cs in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   select new { Compliance = c, Value = cs!=null ? cs.Status : (bool?)null })

                 });
```

resulting in

[image]

You can't have a strongly typed result for an arbitary number of different `Compliance` values, but you could convert the result of the `Join` into a `Dictionary<string, bool?>` using the `ToDictionary` method.